# Submit form with first button which is enabled in a form with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form which has 3 different buttons that are enabled/disabled at different times.

```
<html>
    <form method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="test"/>
        <button name="submit1" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button disabled name="submit2" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button disabled name="submit3" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

By default, the first button is enabled. If my focus is inside of a form element, and I press enter, this button is triggered and it submits the form, the other buttons are disabled.

However, if I enable the 2nd button and disable the 1st button, the form does not submit at all when I press enter.

How can I make the `enter` key submit the form using the first button which is not disabled? On any given tab, the user will only be able to see a single submit button, and it will be the ONLY submit button on the whole page which is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to place a hidden submit button at the top of the form that can always handle the enter key event.

```
<form method="GET">
    <button hidden type="submit"></button>
    <input type="text" name="test"/>
    <button disabled name="submit1" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button name="submit2" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't necessarily need to differentiate which tab they are on, however, I need to know which submit button is not disabled (they each have a different `name` attribute). Might be able to work something out with this answer

Comment: Isn't knowing which tab they're on the same as knowing which submit button is not disabled? `change_tab` seems to enforce that all submit buttons not on the current tab are disabled.

Comment: You are correct. Knowing which tab they are on does determine which button is active, however, not directly. I don't really see a need for _another_ hidden input when I already added a hidden button (from your answer), so what I did just now (and tested, it worked) was I added `$('#submit_type').attr('name', type + '_submit');` to my `change_tab()` function which changes the _name_ of the hidden button to the same name as the button I would normally click to submit. (Which is essentially the same as the suggestion in your answer, except without adding a whole other hidden input)

Comment: That was my first thought, but I'm not sure what gets sent to the server if the user decides to click a button rather than hit enter to submit. That's why I suggested the additional hidden input.

Comment: Yeah I tested that as well and it seems to work. I think it only works because the submit button doesn't send an actual value, just the name

Comment: Hey, I changed my question a bit to make it more helpful to future visitors by simplifying it. It did _slightly_ invalidate your answer, specifically the part after your code snippet (which, while definitely helpful and appreciated, it wasn't really part of my question)

Comment: Haha no worries. Just as long as people get the answers they need.

Comment: Yeah for sure, I was just letting you know because I think it would be better if you removed the invalidated section from your answer, since it doesn't really go with the question

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I see for having only one form action and several submit buttons is when we want to do extra tasks just before submitting the form.

I have been on that situation before and a solution would be simple. To start, there is no reason to have multiple submit buttons if, in the end, the form action is only one, so my suggestion is to keep the idea of a default hidden submit button but with an ID to target it and trigger a click event on it.

You can try this sample code I have created in **TryIt Editor**
[Sample code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G5XJ6TARMKWI)

I have commented out the submit action in all three event handlers to avoid page reload caused by the form submission. You will see that it is possible to have an instance of the form inside each tab content and there is a selector for the form inside its tab, it is commented out just in case that is your use case but if that is the case you must remove the form instance outside the tabs just to avoid troubles even if `document.querySelector('#' + tabName + 'multi-submit-form')` targets only the first occurrence.

I hope this answer illustrate de idea and flexibility of having as many controls you might want but only one submit that can be triggered when you need.

Comment: This isn't my full or actual form I'm using in my code, it has a lot more elements. Each button triggers a different action

Comment: Different action or different form action? Still unclear.

Comment: It makes my php preform a different set of actions, not a different form action